# Preserving Formula in Excel Python XLWT

Tags: python, excel, formula, xlrd, xlwt

I am working on the XLWT XLRD XLUTIL packages. Whenever I write to a new sheet, all the formulas have been obliterated.

I tried the following fixes, but they all failed:

1. Re-write all the formulas in with a loop:

   Failure: XLWT Formula does not support advanced i.e. VLOOKUP Formulas
2. Doing the calculations all in Python: this is ridiculous

How can I preserve the formulas using the above packages? Can I use some other packages to solve my problem? Or, do I need to code my own solution?

Answer (score 1):

(a) xlrd does not currently support extracting formulas.

(b) You say "XLWT Formula does not support advanced i.e. VLOOKUP Formulas". This is incorrect. If you are the same person that I seem to have convinced that xlwt supports VLOOKUP etc after a lengthy exchange of private emails over the last few days, please say so. Otherwise please supply a valid (i.e. Excel accepts it) formula that xlwt won't parse correctly.

(c) Doing the calculations in Python is not ridiculous if the output is only for display.